# How to fix 'File not found' in var_dump when using DOCXTemplate class in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using DOCXTemplate class from https://www.phpclasses.org/package/8247-PHP-Create-Microsoft-Word-documents-from-templates.html, to create docx document with the data stored in database with docx template. When I try to use that class, I just copy the class file into my view folder, and create new php file to execute the class, in reference to example included in class file, the file is named `download.php`. This is my code:

```
<?php
    include "docxtemplate.class.php";

    $docx = new DOCXTemplate('template.docx');
    var_dump($docx);

    $docx->set('nama', 'Firlhi');
    $docx->set('jenis_kelamin', 'Laki-Laki');
    $docx->set('alamat', 'Tarakan');
    $docx->set('tgl_lahir', '21/01/1996');
    $docx->set('proyek', 'Pembangunan');

    $docx->downloadAs("evaluasi.docx");

?>
```

But it returns error, var_dump result is:

```
object(DOCXTemplate)#19 (5) { ["data":"DOCXTemplate":private]=> array(0) { } ["package":"DOCXTemplate":private]=> NULL ["error":"DOCXTemplate":private]=> string(14) "File not found" ["debug"]=> bool(false) ["datasec"]=> array(0) { } }
```

And PHP error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: dashboard_guest/docxtemplate.class.php
>
> Line Number: 271
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\bank_garansi\application\views\dashboard_guest\docxtemplate.class.php
>   Line: 271 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\bank_garansi\application\views\dashboard_guest\docxtemplate.class.php
>   Line: 60 Function: getEntryData
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\bank_garansi\application\views\dashboard_guest\docxtemplate.class.php
>   Line: 423 Function: _parse
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\bank_garansi\application\views\dashboard_guest\download.php
>   Line: 13 Function: downloadAs
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\bank_garansi\application\controllers\Dashboard_guest.php
>   Line: 20 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp2\htdocs\bank_garansi\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

I've tried to create new folder in htdocs, and just create the class file, download file, and template.docx same as in codeigniter view folder and it works. But when I try in codeigniter it's error. In my opinion, the error source is the template.docx inside the view folder, how should I put that file?

I want to use the class into the codeigniter, help me to fix that file location and use the DOCXTemplate class properly. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should be providing the path to the file. Where does it actually live?

Comment: I put the file inside same folder as the class file, in view folder.
i already try:
    $docx = new DOCXTemplate(base_url() . 'index.php/mycontroller/download/template.docx');

Comment: Ok can you provide the actual path if you were to type it out manually?

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the ball rolling here...

In this cutdown, see what can be done, example I have a file called test.txt located in the project under \application\views\test.txt.

I am guessing that is where you said your file was but it isn't clear. So alter to suit.

```
$filename = APPPATH.'views/test.txt'; // Path and Filename

// This is the test used in the docxtemplate class
if(!is_readable($filename)){
    echo "Error Finding Files";
} else {
    echo "I found it!";
}
```

And this results in "I found it!" being displayed

The clue here is the use of **APPPATH** which gives the path up to and including the application folder. Then you need to add the rest.

So hopefully that gives you a better picture on how to provide the path to your template file.

Answer (score 0):

I already fix it by removing the base_url and keep the path. Thanks for help!